# solve a discontinuous ODE

Tags: pyomo

I am a newcomer in PyOmo and I want to simulate an hybrid system where we have an ODE, i.e.,

```
C1[t] ==0 for t<=td
dC1[t] == -m.k*m.C1[t] for t>td
```

where td is parameter

How to program this in pyOmo? Any tips are welcome

Comment: Is td a known, fixed value? Is this equation truly discontinuous or is it continuous but not smooth?

Comment: td is known a priori. In practice, the equation is discontinuous. The discontinuity is explicit (known at the beginning) .